# AWS S3 - Block direct access to image URL but allow the Mobile APP to use it

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Allo,

I'm using AWS S3 to store some images that come and go from an App through an REST Api built in PHP.

My question is, if there's a way to block the direct access to the URL Image on AWS, but allow the image to be shown on the App when the App makes de Api Call.

I know that i can create a signed URL, but i think that for a mobile App is not a good approach.

Any help ?

Comment: Not possible 100% reliably. Not everyone sends a referer, and that's the ONLY thing you have to check if it's a direct/indirect access.

Comment: But there must be a way, maybe not on the Amazon side, to keep the profile picture of an user private with no direct access throught the URL but available on the App, no ?

Comment: if it's accessible by url, then it's accessible from anywhere. if you have a php script serving it up, then you've just moved the goalposts. now you have to figure out how to protect access to the php url and are in exactly the same spot again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using signed URLs is the only reliable way to conditionally allow access to your S3 objects.

If you don't want to use signed URLs and your mobile app uses a specific user agent in all the requests, you could add a bucket policy to your S3 bucket that only allows access to users with your targeted user agent.

See the `aws:UserAgent` string condition and the following AWS docs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#AvailableKeys

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html